# Can RDMA be used to write to memory-mapped registers?

Tags: x86, dma, bus, memory-mapping, rdma

How are memory accesses to memory-mapped registers intercepted and routed to the correct device (rather than letting them go through to RAM)? Is it possible to use RDMA to write to a memory-mapped register? I suppose the answer to this question is dependent on where the translation from a physical address to a register occurs.

To clarify, RDMA is a version of DMA that works over a network. One computer can access the memory of another computer without a CPU being involved on either side.

Comment: Within the target computer, I think the infiniband or firewire (or whatever other RDMA) device is "just" a PCIe device making the same kind of write-to-memory transactions that any other device would.  i.e. the remote initiation is not special as far as whether or not a PCIe device can write to MMIO regions of other devices.  I'd assume that it can, but I'm not posting an answer because this is pure guesswork on my part based on no real experience or checking of docs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the quick response! One more quick thing before I start writing code to try it out. When the local APIC has the xAPIC architecture, its registers can be memory-mapped. Do you still predict it is possible to write to the local APIC's registers (for any core) using RDMA? Basically I'm trying to get a remote device on the network to trigger an interrupt on a specific core in the local machine. I'm using polling to check for packets in the RX queue, so I can't do something simple like sending a network packet. Any suggestions for the latter problem are welcome.

Comment: RDMA definitely cannot write to the local APIC's memory mapped registers. Those are only accessible by the CPU.

Comment: @prl Yeah that's what I was expecting.

Comment: I agree with Peter's guess that the RDMA device can write to MMIO regions in the same way that any other device can. If an IOMMU is enabled, the RDMA addresses are subject to DMA address remapping.

Comment: A Message-Signalled Interrupt is simply a DWORD write to a special address, FEExxxxx. The low 20 bits of the address indicate the destination of the interrupt, and the data value written indicates the vector. Look up details on the format of message-signalled interrupts for more information.

Comment: @prl Thanks! I will read up on that now and hopefully get it working with RoCE. You two are always a big help to me. Thanks!

Comment: @prl Just out of curiosity, can an x86 core send an MSI? Or can only a PCIe device send one? I want to test it from an x86 core if possible as an easy way to make sure I'm getting the format of the address and the value down, but it doesn't seem like x86 can send one based on my test and some vague language online. The manual doesn't specify but it seems to suggest that only PCIe devices can send them.

Comment: It is generally possible to use PCIe peer to peer transactions to write to other devices (see [P2PMEM](https://lwn.net/Articles/718593/) and [PeerDirect](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-implement-peerdirect-client-using-mlnx-ofed)). I don't know whether that works for the APIC though.

Comment: No, a core can’t generate an MSI. To generate an interrupt from software, you write to the Interrupt Command Register (ICR) of the APIC.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just an update on this. I got in touch with the vendor of the RoCE device and they said that there is no deterministic way to trigger interrupts from the device. Thus, I can't test this out. I don't know if it's a device limitation or if it is not possible to trigger MSIs with RDMA.